# Determining the location of staves in sheet music

Tags: c++, image-processing, omr

I want to be able to determine the location of staves in sheet music.  Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXPSo.jpg

The sheet music could be scanned and so could be skewed, have gaps etc.  I've spent some time researching various methods (the Hough transform seems to crop up a lot) and looking at how staves are recognised in the OpenOMR project, but so far I've not been able to find a definitive answer.  Once I have then I can go ahead and start developing it (Obj C or C++) if a library does not exist, but I don't want to start going down the wrong route!  Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well my advise is to go with a [blob extraction algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_extraction)

See it in action [here](http://sudokugrab.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-does-it-all-work.html)

Comment: I have gone with a combination of blob extraction and then hough transform which seems to work well. Thanks.